# Variable speed of light in loop quantum gravity

Tags: speed-of-light, loop-quantum-gravity

Loop quantum gravity predicts a variable speed of light. What is the range of such a variation in its speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll paraphrase my answer to your twin question, saying mainly that breaking Lorentz invariance doesn't necessarily break the constancy of c

- loop quantum gravity theories discuss of the Lorentz invariance but most of them consider c with a constant value.

in the wikipedia page of the [Lorentz invariance in loop quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_invariance_in_loop_quantum_gravity) , you can read :

> [Lorentz invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_invariance) is a measure of universal features in hypothetical
>   loop quantum gravity universes. The various hypothetical multiverse
>   loop quantum gravity universe design models, could have various
>   Lorentz invariance results.

Why physicists try to keep c constant when they build speculative theories ? they play with a set of variables and mathematical tools. The latter were developped with c constant. Generally, theorists are in favor changing anything but not c , letting them a contact with the hub. Even if modification of the constancy of c would likely imply to evolve its exact meaning.

a little further in the same page :

> These and other considerations, including difficulties interpreting
>   what it would mean to apply a Lorentz transformation to a spin network
>   state, led Lee Smolin and others to **suggest that spin network states
>   must break Lorentz invariance**. Lee Smolin and Joao Magueijo then went
>   on to study **doubly special relativity, in which not only there is a
>   constant velocity c but also a constant distance l**.

Notice than in General relativity, c is postulated **locally** constant. Potential pitfalls at another scales are handled by the flexibility of the spacetime properties in differrent models.